# Robust image hashing algorithm implementation?

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv

Is there any robust image hashing implementation in any programming language that I can use? This image hashing at minimum be able to generate the same hash for images that are altered in minor form (resized, rotated, minor touch, cropped etc ) .

The best example will be Tineye.com. They somehow hash each image and they are able to detect other duplicate images with minor modification.

I found some research but not implementation.
 http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0,10&q=robust+image+hashing

Comment: "Hash" may not be the best word choice for what you are looking for. One usual meaning of hash is a function that will have a completely different output even if a bit changes in the input, which is exactly what you don't want. Keywords that might help you are "scale/rotation/crop invariant image descriptor" or "scale/rotation/crop invariant image features".

Comment: You can also check http://www.intel-research.net/Publications/Pittsburgh/101220041412_279.pdf.